# Issue with relationship in SQL Server and Vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, relationship

I have a table of "CASH PAYMENT". I created two tables in SQL Server 2008 and did drag and drop in vb.net 2010.

Now when I save it with default update code, I get different errors.

I do not have any idea of relationships. I searched the web about it but did not find anything related to it. Also, what code can I use to update my relationship entry for vb.net using SQL Server?

I tried nothing - I only drag and drop the SQL Server database in vb.net and with default update code I got error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_cash-entries_cash-entries". The conflict occurred in database "dbo_main", table "dbo.cash_payn_details", column 'autonumber'

Code is shown below. This is the default code when drag drop SQL Server in vb.net

```
Me.Validate()
    Me.Cash_payn_detailsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Dbo_mainDataSet)
    Me.Cash_entriesBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.Cash_entriesTableAdapter.Update(Me.Dbo_mainDataSet)
```

I want to save two tables with one reference number. I am a beginner in vb.net and SQL Server relationships.

### Edit

Table structure:

```
 USE [dbo_main]
        GO
        
        /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[cash_payn_details]    Script Date: 01/04/2019 17:44:25 ******/
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO
        
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
        
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cash_payn_details](
            [autonumber] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
            [account] [nchar](10) NULL,
            [amount] [nchar](10) NULL,
            [date] [nchar](10) NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_cash_payn_details] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [autonumber] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
        
        GO
        
        
        OTHER IS
        
        USE [dbo_main]
        GO
        
        /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[cash-entries]    Script Date: 01/04/2019 17:45:08 ******/
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO
        
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
        
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cash-entries](
            [des_autonumber] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
            [system_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
            [entries] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_cash-entries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [des_autonumber] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
        
        GO
        
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cash-entries]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_cash-entries_cash-entries] FOREIGN KEY([system_ID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[cash_payn_details] ([autonumber])
        GO
        
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cash-entries] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_cash-entries_cash-entries]
        GO
        
      
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo_main].[dbo].[cash-entries]
               ([des_autonumber]
               ,[system_ID]
               ,[entries])
         VALUES
               (<des_autonumber, nchar(10),>
               ,<system_ID, nchar(10),>
               ,<entries, nvarchar(50),>)
    GO
    
    
    other is
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo_main].[dbo].[cash_payn_details]
               ([autonumber]
               ,[account]
               ,[amount]
               ,[date])
         VALUES
               (<autonumber, nchar(10),>
               ,<account, nchar(10),>
               ,<amount, nchar(10),>
               ,<date, nchar(10),>)
    GO
```

Comment: show your  CREATE TABLE statements, the data in your tables  and the data you want to INSERT

Comment: i posted the codes below..i do not have any data yet and i want to insert payment in two tables .....one is details and other is only for related entries

Comment: Forgerein key ==> the system_ID you trying too add on table cash-entries does exist before on table cash_payn_details 'autonumber' field

Comment: no i made relation of autonumber from table one (cash-payment-details TO system ID in cash-entries.

Comment: It seems like an auto-number field of type nVarChar is not a good idea.

Comment: what should i use instead of nVarChar

Comment: i tried by changing nvarchar to int but still same